# Deixar input em focus, após alert

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário que válida se o cpf ou cnpj digitados são válidos, porém se apresentar erro ele muda para o input seguinte, mas gostaria que o mesmo permanecesse no input cpf ainda para validação.

Exemplo:

```js
$('#doc').blur(function(){
 var tam = $('#doc').val();
 if(tam > 11){
 alert('cpf invalido');
 tam = '';
 tam.focus();
 return false;
 }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="doc">Cpf | Cnpj:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="doc" name="doc" type="text" placeholder="Isnira o cpf ou cnpj" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nome">Nome:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome completo" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Telefone:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente é interessante validar se o **CPF** ou **CNPJ** são validos, no código coloquei duas funções javascript para verificar isso `validaCPF` e `validaCNPJ`.

para que o foco fique no seu input, basta por isso:

```
$('#doc').focus();
```

```js
jafoicnpj = true;
jafoicpf = true;

$('#doc').blur(function(){
  
});

function myFunction(){

 var tam = $('#doc').val().length;
 var tam_valor = $('#doc').val();
 
 if(tam < 8){
  return false;
 }
 
 var podecontinuar = false;
 
 if(tam == 14){
    podecontinuar = validarCNPJ(tam_valor);
    if(!podecontinuar && jafoicnpj){alert('nao é um cnpj valido')};
    jafoicnpj = false;
 }
 
 if(tam == 11){
    podecontinuar = TestaCPF(tam_valor);
    if(!podecontinuar){alert('nao é um cpf valido')};
    jafoicpf = false;
 }
 
 if(!podecontinuar){
  
   $('#doc').focus();
 }

}


function validarCNPJ(cnpj) {

 cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');

 if(cnpj == '') return false;
 
 if (cnpj.length != 14)
  return false;

 // Elimina CNPJs invalidos conhecidos
 if (cnpj == "00000000000000" || 
  cnpj == "11111111111111" || 
  cnpj == "22222222222222" || 
  cnpj == "33333333333333" || 
  cnpj == "44444444444444" || 
  cnpj == "55555555555555" || 
  cnpj == "66666666666666" || 
  cnpj == "77777777777777" || 
  cnpj == "88888888888888" || 
  cnpj == "99999999999999")
  return false;
  
 // Valida DVs
 tamanho = cnpj.length - 2
 numeros = cnpj.substring(0,tamanho);
 digitos = cnpj.substring(tamanho);
 soma = 0;
 pos = tamanho - 7;
 for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
   soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
   if (pos < 2)
   pos = 9;
 }
 resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
 if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
  return false;
  
 tamanho = tamanho + 1;
 numeros = cnpj.substring(0,tamanho);
 soma = 0;
 pos = tamanho - 7;
 for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
   soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
   if (pos < 2)
   pos = 9;
 }
 resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
 if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
    return false;
    
 return true;
   
}


function TestaCPF(strCPF) {
    var Soma;
    var Resto;
    Soma = 0;
 if (strCPF == "00000000000") return false;
    
 for (i=1; i<=9; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i-1, i)) * (11 - i);
 Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;
 
    if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11))  Resto = 0;
    if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(9, 10)) ) return false;
 
 Soma = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i-1, i)) * (12 - i);
    Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;
 
    if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11))  Resto = 0;
    if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(10, 11) ) ) return false;
    return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Form Name</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="doc">Cpf | Cnpj:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="doc" name="doc" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Isnira o cpf ou cnpj" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nome">Nome:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome completo" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Telefone:</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" class="form-control input-md">
    
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Fiz uma edição em minha resposta pois tinha encontrado um erro.

Answer (score 2):

Tinha alguns erros de codificação, que era pegar o valor do campo e dar um `focus`, ou seja, não representa a caixa de texto e sim o valor contido nela, outros porém, era a forma de utilizar o [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) que estava errado, então fiz um exemplo minimo para que possa verificar se é isso que precisa:

```js
$('#doc').blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 11) {
    alert('cpf invalido');
    $(this).val('');
    $(this).focus();    
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Form Name</legend>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="doc">Cpf | Cnpj:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="doc" name="doc" type="text" placeholder="Isnira o cpf ou cnpj" class="form-control input-md">

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nome">Nome:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome completo" class="form-control input-md">

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Telefone:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" class="form-control input-md">

      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Uma solução com verificação para `CPF` e `CNPJ`:

```js
$('#doc').blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 0) return;
  var sts = false; 
  if ($(this).val().length == 11) {
    sts = validate_cpf($(this).val());    
  } else {
    if ($(this).val().length == 14) {
      sts = validate_cnpj($(this).val());      
    }
  }  
  if (!sts) {    
    $(this).val('');
    alert('Cpf/Cnpj invalido');
    $(this).focus();
  }
});

function validate_cnpj(cnpj) {

  cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');

  if (cnpj == '') return false;

  // Elimina CNPJs invalidos conhecidos
  if (cnpj.length != 14 || cnpj == "00000000000000" ||
    cnpj == "11111111111111" || cnpj == "22222222222222" ||
    cnpj == "33333333333333" || cnpj == "44444444444444" ||
    cnpj == "55555555555555" || cnpj == "66666666666666" ||
    cnpj == "77777777777777" || cnpj == "88888888888888" ||
    cnpj == "99999999999999")
    return false;

  // Valida DVs
  length = cnpj.length - 2
  numbers = cnpj.substring(0, length);
  digit = cnpj.substring(length);
  sum = 0;
  pos = length - 7;
  for (i = length; i >= 1; i--) {
    sum += numbers.charAt(length - i) * pos--;
    if (pos < 2)
      pos = 9;
  }
  result = sum % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - sum % 11;
  if (result != digit.charAt(0))
    return false;

  length = length + 1;
  numbers = cnpj.substring(0, length);
  sum = 0;
  pos = length - 7;
  for (i = length; i >= 1; i--) {
    sum += numbers.charAt(length - i) * pos--;
    if (pos < 2)
      pos = 9;
  }
  result = sum % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - sum % 11;
  if (result != digit.charAt(1))
    return false;

  return true;

}

function validate_cpf(strCPF) {
  var Soma;
  var Resto;
  Soma = 0;
  if (strCPF == "00000000000") return false;

  for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i - 1, i)) * (11 - i);
  Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;

  if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11)) Resto = 0;
  if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(9, 10))) return false;

  Soma = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i - 1, i)) * (12 - i);
  Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11;

  if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11)) Resto = 0;
  if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(10, 11))) return false;
  return true;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Form Name</legend>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="doc">Cpf | Cnpj:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="doc" name="doc" type="text" placeholder="Isnira o cpf ou cnpj" class="form-control input-md">

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nome">Nome:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome completo" class="form-control input-md">

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Telefone:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" class="form-control input-md">

      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```